# Can a mixed model random slope include a between-subjects factor in a repeated measures design?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, gamma-distribution

I'm after some statistics help with generalised linear mixed models. I have built a model using glmer from the lmerTest package in R to fit my data with a gamma distribution. The formula is as follows:

```
gammaFPtime4_id <- glmer(firstPress ~ Condition + tStyle  + Condition:tStyle + PHQ9 
                       + Condition:PHQ9 + Order + Condition:Order + (1 | Word) + 
                          (1 + Condition * PHQ9 | ParticipantID), 
                         family = Gamma(link = "identity"),
                         nAGQ = 0,
                         glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 500000)),
                         data = fpDatamut)
```

As you can see I have added a random slope term (1 + Condition * PHQ9 | ParticipantID), which is theoretically relevant. However, I have a repeated measures design, so every participant completed each level of my treatment (Condition), which is a categorical variable, but there is only one PHQ9 value (numeric) for each participant because this is a depression score measured just once at the start of the study. It was pointed out to me that having the PHQ9 (depression) score in a random slope doesn't make sense because there won't be variation within the level of participant.

BUT here's where I'm getting confused. Including the PHQ9 in that random slope is accounting for some variation in the data (1.572e+01), and when I include it in the model, the model has a lower AIC value than when I change that slope to just (1 + Condition | ParticipantID) - so what is the (1 + Condition * PHQ9 | ParticipantID) slope actually doing?

I have found this entry here, which poses a similar question: [Can we really assign random slopes to between-subject effects in a mixed effects model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/408973/can-we-really-assign-random-slopes-to-between-subject-effects-in-a-mixed-effects/408983#408983)
But the solution deals with a random intercept instead of a slope and I'm not sure how this would apply to my own model?

Any ideas hugely appreciated! I haven't provided my data set or a reproducible example because my dataset is quite large and I was hoping someone could help illuminate the statistics behind this problem as opposed to the R code, but if more information is required please let me know and I'll do my best to add that in.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand the design of your study. Condition is actually the treatment and it's a categorical variable with several levels. Each subject is observed at each Condition level. On the other hand PHQ9 is a numeric variable (depression score) and each subject has a single depression score (which either is assumed not to change during the treatment or is measured only once at the start of the study)?

Comment: Hi @dipetkov and thanks for the comment. Apologies if I didn't make that clear. Your assumptions are all correct. The depression score (PHQ9) is measured only once at the start of the study.